# Creating json but sending XML out instead in WSO2 ESB

Tags: json, api, wso2-esb

In WSO2 ESB 4.8.1, implemented an API, which receives json message, and will send new json payload to the backend. I debug the API and I saw that it is convert my json payload to xml and then send it to the backend.

FYI: I have un-commented the json stream formatter and builder in axis2 config files.

the api source is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<api xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="SdpProductStatus" context="/SdpServices/1/Aggregator/Product/Status">
   <resource methods="POST">
      <inSequence>
         <property name="messageType" value="application/json; charset=utf-8;" scope="axis2" type="STRING" />
         <property name="ContentType" value="application/json; charset=utf-8;" scope="axis2" type="STRING" />
         <property name="productId" expression="json-eval($.productId)" scope="default" type="STRING" />
         <property name="customerId" expression="json-eval($.customerId)" scope="default" type="STRING" />
         <property name="description" expression="json-eval($.description)" scope="default" type="STRING" />
         <property name="time" expression="json-eval($.time)" scope="default" type="STRING" />
         <property name="state" expression="json-eval($.state)" scope="default" type="STRING" />
         <log />
         <property name="time" expression="concat(substring($ctx:time,1,4),'-',substring($ctx:time,5,2),'-',substring($ctx:time,7,2),' ',substring($ctx:time,10,2),':',substring($ctx:time,12,2),':',substring($ctx:time,14,2))" scope="default" type="STRING" />
         <script language="js">mc.setProperty("state", mc.getProperty("state").replace("0","deactive")); mc.setProperty("state", mc.getProperty("state").replace("1","active"));</script>
         <property name="POST_TO_URI" value="true" scope="axis2" />
         <property name="REST_URL_POSTFIX" value="ActiveOrDeactive" scope="axis2" type="STRING" />
         <property name="FORCE_HTTP_CONTENT_LENGTH" value="true" scope="axis2" type="STRING" />
         <property name="messageType" value="application/json; charset=utf-8;" scope="axis2" type="STRING" />
         <property name="ContentType" value="application/json; charset=utf-8;" scope="axis2" type="STRING" />
         <header name="Accept" scope="transport" value="application/json" />
         <header name="Content-Type" scope="transport" value="application/json" />
         <header name="ContentType" scope="transport" value="application/json" />
         <payloadFactory media-type="json">
            <format>{"productID":"$1","CustomerID":"$2", "Time":"$3","State":"$4","tempData":"$5","Description":"$6","Username":"$7","Password":"$8", "Instruction":"$9"}</format>
            <args>
               <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:productId" />
               <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:customerId" />
               <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:time" />
               <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:state" />
               <arg evaluator="xml" value="temp" />
               <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:description" />
               <arg value="test1" />
               <arg value="test1" />
               <arg value="create" />
            </args>
         </payloadFactory>
         <log>
            <property name="body" expression="json-eval($.)" />
         </log>
         <send buildmessage="true">
            <endpoint>
               <address uri="http://10.8.10.10:8080/service1.svc/" />
            </endpoint>
         </send>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <log />
         <property name="message" expression="json-eval($.MESSAGE)" scope="default" type="STRING" />
         <filter source="json-eval($.STATUS)" regex="-?\d.*">
            <then>
               <property name="statusCode" value="200" scope="default" type="STRING" />
            </then>
            <else>
               <property name="statusCode" expression="json-eval($.STATUS)" scope="default" type="STRING" />
            </else>
         </filter>
         <property name="messageType" value="application/json" scope="axis2" type="STRING" />
         <header name="Accept" scope="transport" value="application/json" />
         <payloadFactory media-type="json">
            <format>{"productId":$1,"id":"$2","customerId":"$3","status":{"statusCode":$4,"message":"$5"}}</format>
            <args>
               <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:productId" />
               <arg evaluator="xml" value="55" />
               <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:customerId" />
               <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:statusCode" />
               <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:message" />
            </args>
         </payloadFactory>
         <header name="Content-Type" scope="transport" value="application/json" />
         <send />
      </outSequence>
   </resource>
</api>
```

And this is what I get in the backend:

```
<jsonobject>....my payload converted to xml...</jsonobject>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you `<header name="Content-Type" scope="transport" value="application/json" />` before building payloadFactory?

```
<property name="messageType" value="application/json" scope="axis2" type="STRING" />
<header name="Accept" scope="transport" value="application/json" />
<header name="Content-Type" scope="transport" value="application/json" />
```

OR

Try like following, here I skip the "evaluator="xml"".

```
       <args>
            <arg expression="$ctx:productId"/>
            <arg value="55"/>
            <arg expression="$ctx:customerId"/>
        </args>
```

Comment: Thank you, that didn't work. But I found the error, I will be write the answer tomorrow, it should be 
`<property name="messageType" value="application/json" scope="axis2" type="STRING" />` not `property name="messageType" value="application/json; charset=utf-8;" scope="axis2" type="STRING" />` at the first line of the api in-sequence.